# Azure WebApp - VM Latency

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, wordpress, cloud

I have a Wordpress environment.

Front end is on WebApp (Size is S2 - 2cores & 3.5 GB RAM) whilst DB on 2 replicated Classic Virtual Machines (Size F2 - 2 cores / 4 GB Memory); Also tested this setup with higher speced environment to no avail.

We also tried connecting the web app to the VMs over a point-to-site VPN which in a nutshell is a VPN from 1 microsoft service (WebApp) to another (VMs), so ultimately connection is still being made over the internet.

I'm looking for ways to improve network latency between Azure's WebApp and Virtual Machines.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure WebApp Vnet intergration. This should connect your WebApp directly to the Vnet that hosts your VMs. so no need to access through the internet.
[image]

more info at this URL:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that however latency was still too high to work with. From what I understand this is basically a VPN connection which ultimately is still made over the internet. Any other proposed solutions ?